# Does Apple test the apps on real device as part of review?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, apple-developer

I want to know if Apple tests the apps on real device while reviewing the app as part of app approval process.

Comment: Yes. Is there any reason you would expect otherwise? How do you think they test it?

Comment: How else could they possibly test your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They certainly do. For one my submissions, apple rejected and the screenshot they had attached was taken from an iPad running my app.

Answer (score 0):

I see they do validate on real device. Also most of their test locations are outside US, like Ireland.

Answer (score -1):

Your application should run the same as on-device and also in a simulator. There should not be any difference in behaviors when submitted to the App Store for review. If you have a check-in code for if the device is the simulator to run in a "development" mode I recommend you change this to check for a launch argument that you define on run in Xcode.